# Tmp array not properly added to state variable - React - Hooks

Tags: arrays, reactjs, foreach, react-hooks, react-state

The `newArray` i create and push url's to, is not added properly to my state variable (`propFiles`)

```
const [propFiles, setPropFiles] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let newArray = [...propFiles];
    data?.forEach((element) => {
      element?.images?.forEach((el) => {
        storageRef
          .child(element.firebaseRef + "/" + el)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            console.log(url) // this returns url's like "https://firebase/my-picture.jpg"
            newArray.push(url);
            console.log(newArray) // this updates the array as expected so the result of newArray is ok
            setPropFiles(...propFiles, newArray) // This is where something goes wrong
          });
      });
    });
  }, [data]);


useEffect(() => {
    console.log(propFiles); // The complete array values (of newArray) are not transfered proper to state. Only the first 2 url's are
  }, [propFiles]);
```

So after each `console.log` you can find my information about what is going on.

As you can see, if i try to log `propFiles`, it only shows me the to 2 first elements of the foreach loop, not the complete `newArray` that was made.

Can someone please explain to me what would be the right approach to `set state` equal to the complete `newArray` that was made?

UPDATE To be extra clear about the outcomes of `newArray` and `propFiles`

This is what `newArray` looks like after the `foreach`:

```
[
    0: "https://firebase/my-picture-1.jpg",
    1: "https://firebase/my-picture-2.jpg",
    2: "https://firebase/my-picture-3.jpg",
    3: "https://firebase/my-picture-4.jpg",
    4: "https://firebase/my-picture-5.jpg",
    5: "https://firebase/my-picture-6.jpg",
    6: "https://firebase/my-picture-7.jpg",
    7: "https://firebase/my-picture-8.jpg",
    8: "https://firebase/my-picture-9.jpg",
    9: "https://firebase/my-picture-10.jpg",
    10: "https://firebase/my-picture-11.jpg",
    11: "https://firebase/my-picture-12.jpg",
]
```

So an `array` with 11 url (or strings) inside of it

This is what `propFiles` look like after it is set equal to `newArray`:

```
[
    0: "https://firebase/my-picture-1.jpg",
    1: "https://firebase/my-picture-2.jpg"
]
```

So an `array` with just 2 urls (or strings) inside of it.

How could this be possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`propFiles` state is an array and hence you are updating it, you should set an array back but you are setting comma separated values

Correct way to update it would be

```
setPropFiles(newArray)
```

since you have already used the `propFiles` while initialising the `newArray`

---

However, another thing to note is that you are looping over elements and updating state, it is always better to get the final updated array and update it only once. The way to do it would be to map over the items and use Promise.all

```
const [propFiles, setPropFiles] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const promises = data?.map((element) => {
      return element?.images?.map((el) => {
        return storageRef
          .child(element.firebaseRef + "/" + el)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            console.log(url) // this returns url's like "https://firebase/my-picture.jpg"

            console.log(newArray) // this updates the array as expected so the result of newArray is ok
            return url
          });
      });
    }).filter(Boolean); // remove all undefined values
  
// flatten the promise array since we have nested maps
const promisesArr = promises?.flat();
promisesArr && Promise.all(promisesArr).then(newArray => {
         setPropFiles(prevPropsFiles => [...prevPropsFiles, ...newArray])
    })
  }, [data]);
```

Comment: Khatri thanks for reply, but still only 2 url's are added to the state with that approach ...

Comment: I tried the answer but this is returning to me the following error: `cannot read property 'flat' of undefined`

Comment: I also updated my question so you can exactly see what the outcomes are of the console.log()'s

Comment: Well is data is undefined, the returned promises will be undeefined. You can use it like `promises?.flat()`

Comment: Tried that already but unfortunately returns an error as well.
`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

Comment: @brunelli updated my answer. See how promise is used in the updatted answer witth Promise.all

Comment: @Khatri error handling is ok now but state is now filled with an array of `undefined` values

Comment: I don't get it, since `console.log(url)` is returning all the correct image url's

Comment: Did you return url from .then and also return from the inner map which calls thee storageRef promise?

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    const promises = data
      ?.map((element) => {
        return element?.images?.map((el) => {
          storageRef
            .child(element.firebaseRef + '/' + el)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then((url) => {
              return url
            })
        })
      })
      .filter(Boolean) 
    const promisesArr = promises?.flat()
    promisesArr &&
      Promise.all(promisesArr).then((newArray) => {
        console.log(newArray)
        setPropFiles((prevPropsFiles) => [...prevPropsFiles, ...newArray])
      })

Comment: storageRef .child(element.firebaseRef + '/' + el) is not getting returneed from the inner map in your implementation

Comment: How do you mean? Isn't it right here ... `.then((url) => { return url })`

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    const promises = data?.map((element) => {
      return element?.images?.map((el) => {
        return storageRef
          .child(element.firebaseRef + "/" + el)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            console.log(url) // this returns url's like "https://firebase/my-picture.jpg"

            console.log(newArray) // this updates the array as expected so the result of newArray is ok
            return url
          });
      });
    }).filter(Boolean); // remove all undefined values`

Comment: Glad to have helped. Consider marking the answer as accepted